# PHP - For loop store all array values as one long string

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I need to store each value in an array as one single string. Is it possible to do this?

I have tried using a for loop to achieve this:

```
for($count = 0; $count < $totalArray; $count++) {
    $x = $array[$count];
}
```

I'm not sure why I thought this would work. it will obviously, keep changing the value and end up as the last value in the array. But can anyone tell me if there is a way to do this?

Comment: [`implode`](http://php.net/implode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the previous total, not set it:

```
$x .= $array[$count];
```

Comment: Or just `implode`

Comment: Indeed, use implode

Comment: He might have needed to do some additional processing though, so just in case I left it mostly how he had it.

Comment: Both have worked fine for me, thanks for the answers!